# Accessing the derived class object inside a base classed list

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

Say I have 3 classes:

```
class Geometry
{ ... }

class Line : Geometry
{ ... }

class Circle : Geometry
{ ... }
```

And I want to put all the objects of `Line` and `Circle` class into a common list, like so:

```
List<Geometry> list = new List<Geometry>();
Line line = new Line();
Circle circle = new Circle();
list.Add(line);
list.Add(circle);
```

My question is that is it allowed? Is it still possible to retrieve the derived class from the list like so:

```
Line newLine = (Line)list[0];
Circle newCircle = (Circle)list[1];
```

If not, then is there a good way to store all these different types of objects under the same list?

Comment: It is allowed and fine to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can store them this way. Since all your objects has a common base, the `Geometry` object, this is fine.

Then when you retrieve them from the list I would suggest you use the `as` operator, like below:

```
Line newLine = list[0] as Line;
```

I would suggest so, because as it is stated in MSDN:

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't 
>   possible, as returns null instead of raising an
>   exception. Consider the following example:

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
List<Geometry> list = new List<Geometry>(); 
Geometry line = new Line(); 
Geometry circle = new Circle(); 
list.Add(line); 
list.Add(circle);
```

and when fetching use `OfType()` to get desired type object(s):

```
List<Line> lines = list.OfType<Line>().ToList(); // get lines
List<Circle> circles = list.OfType<Circle>().ToList(); // get circles
```

Comment: OfType() returns an IEnumerable not a List. this won't compile :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's allowed since `Line` and `Circle` are `Geometry`:

```
  List<Geometry> list = new List<Geometry>() {
    new Line(),
    new Circle()
  };
```

You'd rather *check* if `Geometry` is `Line`, `Circle` etc:

```
  Line newLine = list[0] as Line;       // Line instance or null
  Circle newCircle = list[1] as Circle; // Circle instance or null
```

To extract all, say, `Line`'s use Linq:

```
  List<Line> lines = list.OfType<Line>().ToList();
```